# scale non-symmetric colormap

Tags: pgfplots, color

I am wondering if there is a automatised way to produce a diverging colormap, which has the center at 0 independent of the data I want to plot?

The way I figured out was using the `mesh min` and `mesh max` values and use the absolute maximum to generate the desired output.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots,filecontents}

\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pgfplotsset{
    compat=newest,
    /pgfplots/colormap={colmap}{
        rgb255=(0,0,139)
        rgb255=(0,0,255)
        rgb255=(0,255,255)
        rgb255=(255,255,255)
        rgb255=(255,255,0)
        rgb255=(255,0,0)
        rgb255=(139,0,0)
    }
}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{test.txt}
    x   y   z
    1000    1000    0.28019
    1002    1000    0.40177
    1004    1000    0.86296
    1006    1000    0.59342
    1008    1000    0.27397
    1010    1000    0.67336
    1000    1002    0.5083
    1002    1002    0.55867
    1004    1002    0.94536
    1006    1002    0.20572
    1008    1002    0.33257
    1010    1002    0.64346
    1000    1004    0.05353
    1002    1004    0.21822
    1004    1004    0.25069
    1006    1004    0.36525
    1008    1004    0.78002
    1010    1004    0.04127
    1000    1006    0.57922
    1002    1006    0.97888
    1004    1006    0.54728
    1006    1006    0.94287
    1008    1006    0.83359
    1010    1006    0.91652
    1000    1008    0.28625
    1002    1008    0.46143
    1004    1008    0.67409
    1006    1008    0.38048
    1008    1008    0.82077
    1010    1008    0.52705
    1000    1010    0.25684
    1002    1010    0.2017
    1004    1010    0.80708
    1006    1010    0.71639
    1008    1010    0.85566
    1010    1010    0.80574
\end{filecontents}

\def\zmin{-0.04127}
\def\zmax{0.97888}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            name=plot1,
            title=without 'meta limits',
            view={0}{90},
            colorbar,
            ]
            
            \addplot3[
            surf,
            shader=interp,
            mesh/rows=3,
            mesh/cols=6,
            mesh/check=false,
            point meta=z,
            ]
            table[
            x=x,
            y=y,
            z=z,
            ] {test.txt};           
        \end{axis}
    
        \begin{axis}[
            name=plot2,
            at={($(plot1.east) + (3cm,0)$)}, 
            anchor=west,
            title=with 'meta limits',
            view={0}{90},
            colorbar,
            ]
            
            \addplot3[
            surf,
            shader=interp,
            mesh/rows=3,
            mesh/cols=6,
            mesh/check=false,
            point meta=z,
            point meta max= \zmax,
            point meta min=-\zmax,
            ]
            table[
            x=x,
            y=y,
            z=z,
            ] {test.txt};           
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In case the data includes mostly posite or negative values I dont want to show also the respective negative or positive values in the colorbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had an additional look at the manual and played around with the `color position` to get the desired output.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots,filecontents}

\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{test.txt}
    x   y   z
    1000    1000    0.28019
    1002    1000    0.40177
    1004    1000    0.86296
    1006    1000    0.59342
    1008    1000    0.27397
    1010    1000    0.67336
    1000    1002    0.5083
    1002    1002    0.55867
    1004    1002    0.94536
    1006    1002    0.20572
    1008    1002    0.33257
    1010    1002    0.64346
    1000    1004    0.05353
    1002    1004    0.21822
    1004    1004    0.25069
    1006    1004    0.36525
    1008    1004    -0.78002
    1010    1004    0.04127
    1000    1006    0.57922
    1002    1006    0.97888
    1004    1006    0.54728
    1006    1006    0.94287
    1008    1006    0.83359
    1010    1006    0.91652
    1000    1008    -0.28625
    1002    1008    0.46143
    1004    1008    0.67409
    1006    1008    0.38048
    1008    1008    0.82077
    1010    1008    0.52705
    1000    1010    0.25684
    1002    1010    0.2017
    1004    1010    0.80708
    1006    1010    0.71639
    1008    1010    0.85566
    1010    1010    1.80574
\end{filecontents}

\def\zmin{-0.78002}
\def\zmax{1.80574}

\pgfplotsset{%
    compat=newest,
    colormap={corr2D}{
        rgb255=(0,0,139);
        rgb255=(0,0,255);
        rgb255=(0,255,255);
        rgb255=(255,255,255);
        rgb255=(255,255,0);
        rgb255=(255,0,0);
        rgb255=(139,0,0);
    },
}

\begin{document}
    
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\zlim}{abs(\zmin) > abs(\zmax) ? abs(\zmin) : abs(\zmax)}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            name=plot1,
            title=without 'meta limits',
            view={0}{90},
            colormap name=corr2D,
            colorbar,
            ]
            
            \addplot3[
            surf,
            shader=interp,
            mesh/rows=3,
            mesh/cols=6,
            mesh/check=false,
            point meta=z,
            ]
            table[
            x=x,
            y=y,
            z=z,
            ] {test.txt};           
        \end{axis}
    
        \begin{axis}[
            name=plot2,
            at={($(plot1.east) + (3cm,0)$)}, 
            anchor=west,
            title=with 'meta limits',
            view={0}{90},
            colormap name=corr2D,
            colorbar,
            ]
            
            \addplot3[
            surf,
            shader=interp,
            mesh/rows=3,
            mesh/cols=6,
            mesh/check=false,
            point meta=z,
            point meta max= \zmax,
            point meta min=-\zmax,
            ]
            table[
            x=x,
            y=y,
            z=z,
            ] {test.txt};           
        \end{axis}
    
        \begin{axis}[
            name=plot2,
            at={($(plot2.east) + (3cm,0)$)}, 
            anchor=west,
            title=with 'meta limits' and scaling,
            view={0}{90},
            colorbar,
            colormap={corr2d2}{
                rgb255(3/3*\zmin/\zlim)=(0,0,139);
                rgb255(2/3*\zmin/\zlim)=(0,0,255);
                rgb255(1/3*\zmin/\zlim)=(0,255,255);
                rgb255(0)=(255,255,255);
                rgb255(1/3*\zmax/\zlim)=(255,255,0);
                rgb255(2/3*\zmax/\zlim)=(255,0,0);
                rgb255(3/3*\zmax/\zlim)=(139,0,0);
            },
            ]
            
            \addplot3[
            surf,
            shader=interp,
            mesh/rows=3,
            mesh/cols=6,
            mesh/check=false,
            point meta=z,
            point meta max=\zmax,
            point meta min=\zmin,
            ]
            table[
            x=x,
            y=y,
            z=z,
            ] {test.txt};           
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I can get the values for `\zmax` and `\zmin` from my output, where I simulate the data or from my [earlier question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/584163/uniform-colormap) and also compare them to get the maximum of their absolute values (`\zlim`).